# Usage of pydantic with mypy

Tags: python, mypy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to write an application using FastAPI which intensively uses pydantic. Also I would like to type-check my code using `mypy`. How can I use type annotations for pydantic and mypy without conflict?

I know about `type: ignore` comments but in my opinion it's some kind of cheating :)

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Schema


class UsersQuery(BaseModel):
    limit: int = Schema(default=100, gt=0, le=100)
    offset: int = Schema(default=0, ge=0)
```

This code works correctly but fails type checking.

mypy output:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Schema", variable has type "int")
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Schema", variable has type "int")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type: ignore` is the only solution for now.

Version 1 of pydantic should be released in a few days where `Field` (which replaces `Schema` in v1) is a function returning `Any` which should fix this problem.

tl;dr wait for v1 to be released and supported by fastapi and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you @SColvin! Will wait for it to release!

Comment: SColvin thanks again! Marked the answer as accepted.